# PM2 maximum call stack reached

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to deploy an application on a ubuntu server. When I use pm2 I get the following error. I have no clue what this stuff means. This is my first time deploying a Nodejs application so I don't have much experience in this regard. Any help will be appreciated! I was trying to use the steps mentioned here: https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-up-nodejs-application-for-production-ubuntu-17352

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at validatePath (internal/fs/utils.js:442:22)
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:749:3)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:71:13)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.resolve (path.js:133:28)
    at Object.toNamespacedPath (path.js:618:32)
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:754:28)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:71:13)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'U:\.pm2\module_conf.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1194:35)
    at module.exports.Client.initFileStructure (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\Client.js:148:10)
    at new module.exports (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\Client.js:37:8)
    at new API (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\API.js:107:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\bin\pm2:23:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.resolve (path.js:133:28)
    at Object.toNamespacedPath (path.js:618:32)
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:754:28)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:71:13)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
    at sync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)

                        -------------

__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\____/\\\\____________/\\\\____/\\\\\\\\\_____
 _\/\\\/////////\\\_\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\__/\\\///////\\\___
  _\/\\\_______\/\\\_\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_\///______\//\\\__
   _\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\/__\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\___________/\\\/___
    _\/\\\/////////____\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\________/\\\//_____
     _\/\\\_____________\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_____/\\\//________
      _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\___/\\\/___________
       _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_
        _\///______________\///______________\///__\///////////////__


                          Runtime Edition

        PM2 is a Production Process Manager for Node.js applications
                     with a built-in Load Balancer.

                Start and Daemonize any application:
                $ pm2 start app.js

                Load Balance 4 instances of api.js:
                $ pm2 start api.js -i 4

                Monitor in production:
                $ pm2 monitor

                Make pm2 auto-boot at server restart:
                $ pm2 startup

                To go further checkout:
                http://pm2.io/


                        -------------

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'U:\.pm2\module_conf.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.Configuration.getAllSync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\Configuration.js:299:26)
    at Object.Configuration.getSync (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\Configuration.js:270:30)
    at new API (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\API.js:116:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\bin\pm2:23:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
fs.js:114
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'U:\.pm2\pm2.log'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at module.exports.Client.launchDaemon (C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\Client.js:219:12)
    at C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\Client.js:103:10
    at C:\Users\amir.hamza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\Client.js:311:14
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Comment: Ever have any luck fixing this?

Comment: @meelash not yet

Comment: Something is very suspicious in your case because the paths are all Windows paths, not ubuntu. Are you perhaps using a Windows machine and you installed pm2 on that, instead of on the ubuntu server? You need to have ssh to the server first and then follow the instructions in your link.

Comment: In my case, I was actually installing on a Windows server and I think it was some interaction between pm2 and an outdated plugin that caused this error. It turned out I didn't need any plugins so I just used pm2 by itself and that works.